# Have HTTP/2 push in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, push, cloudflare, http2

I search to have my images pushed via HTTP/2 on my Wordpress websites, one is Linorhiati.ch for exemple I am about to finish.

The hoster, I have a cloud subscription at TMDHosting, offers HTTP/2 and also Cloudflare I am using.

I read this article from them about this topic: https://blog.cloudflare.com/using-http-2-server-push-with-php/

So I wonder how to implement these codes in Wordpress in order to have such Link headers in the HTTP response.

Comment: you need to be able to set HTTP headers to do so. I don't know wordpress, but it looks like there's a way to add custom headers in it: https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I allready had added the code below to the <head> section in the header.php:

<?php 
header("Link: </wp-content/uploads/2018/04/water-1330252_1920-dark-low-contrast-c.jpg>; rel=preload); 
header("Link: <wp-content/uploads/2018/04/beach-1824855_1920-dark-low-contrast-c.jpg>; rel=preload); 
header("Link: <wp-content/uploads/2018/04/vitadesign-logo-website-C-400x81.png>; rel=preload); 
?>

Comment: Maybe have to no put it in side a PHP code like this: Link: </wp-content/uploads/2018/04/water-1330252_1920-dark-low-contrast-c.jpg>; rel=preload) for exemple.

Comment: Besides, the website in question is vitadesign.ch ( may appear slow now cause I have most server-side diabled as I am working on it), and HTPP/2 I test here: http://http2-push.io/

Comment: Removing the php code around as menitioned in second-previous comment did not make it work either.